# CakePHP3: How to automate the conversion of decimal (money) fields when saving to the database?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm developing a website for brazillian users. All the money fields on the frontend uses the pattern 1.234,56. To do this, I'm using the [mask.js](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) plugin with the mask `$('.mask-dinheiro').mask("000.000.000.000,00", {reverse: true});`

This project is in the beginning so I'm converting to MySQL common pattern (1234.56) field by field on the controllers. But is there a way to make this conversion implict on saving data on database? I have already set `'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'pt_BR')`, on config/app.php but this does not work to do what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a Behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#creating-a-behavior), then add a [`beforeSave()`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave) or [`beforeMarshall()`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforemarshal) to convert any fields that need converting.

Comment: Well remembered. I created a behavior that works like a charm: https://pastebin.com/HuTEMMYs. Thank you.